# Webhook notifications with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to build an application that gets notified about changes in the calendar of anyone within the organization.

When I look in the documentation for Microsoft graph API, it looks like when one creates a subscription, it can only be for a specific user's resources (in my case it would be Calendar). Is there a way to create a subscription to listen for changes to any users calendar within the organization instead of one user's calendar?

Comment: Please provide the part of source code that you are trying to archive it so that people can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Jerry. I haven't written code yet. I am trying to determine if its possible to listen for changes for all users with 1 subscription as apposed to a subscription per user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app uses an app-only permission (as opposed to user-delegated permission) it will have access to resources for all users in the organization.

`Calendars.Read` is what you need in this case. Keep in mind that this permission requires admin consent.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Peter. Using an app-only permission for the app and giving it admin consent makes sense. Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0], the resource I'd need to specify in the subscription appears to be of the form: users/<user-id>/calendar/events. 
So, appears that I'd still have to create a subscription per user. How would I specify the resource so its one subscription for Calendar update events across all users in the Organization?

Comment: With resources stored in Outlook/Exchange, it is not possible to subscribe across multiple users. An app will need one subscription per mailbox or calendar.